# Python Request is beeing blocked by website

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I want to connect to a Website via Python request

```
import requests
from fake_useragent import UserAgent


ua = UserAgent()
print(ua.chrome)
url = 'https://prnt.sc/dv6373'
headers = {"User_Agent": str(ua.firefox)}
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True, headers=headers)
path = "C:/Users/sobol/Desktop/test.html"
file = open(path, 'wb').write(r.con
```

If i connect with a real browser it will show the website but if I use this script the resulting file contains an Error "502" Connecting to Google work fine thoug. The Header contains "python requests" in front of the header i wrote maybe this is the error but i am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `User-Agent` HTTP header (not `User_Agent` - notice the `-`):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://prnt.sc/dv6373"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# print "screenshot-image":
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
print(soup.select_one(".screenshot-image")["src"])
```

Prints:

```
https://image.prntscr.com/image/292d876a6e024586b192ce7b3e89c4a3.png
```